# Can the VSTS REST API for Policy make changes to "Reset code reviewer votes on new changes"?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to write a script that goes to all branches with a policy and sets the policy option (shown below) as true. The JSON showing the available policy types that you can fetch/edit can be found at the following URL:

https://<*Account Domain*>.visualstudio.com/<*Project Name*>/_apis/policy/types/

Unfortunately, I do not see an option for **Reset code reviewer votes when there are new changes**. Is it impossible to makes changes from the REST API?

[image: Reset code reviewer option]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the option **Reset code reviewer votes when there are new changes** option in branch policies, it belongs to the the policy type **Minimum number of reviewers** (`fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd`).

And when you specify the options for the branch type **Minimum number of reviewers**, there are four parameters you can specify:

- `minimumApproverCount`: Minimum number of reviewers.
- `creatorVoteCounts`: Allow users to approve their own changes.
- `allowDownvotes`: Allow completion even if some reviewers vote “Waiting” or “Reject”.
- `resetOnSourcePush`: Reset code reviewer votes when there are new changes.

Such as add branch policies Minimum number of reviewers as 1 and select Reset code reviewer votes when there are new changes for the branches start with `features/` in repo `ad3acf8e-b269-48e5-81bc-354251856b51`, you can use the request body as:

```
{
  "isEnabled": true,
  "isBlocking": false,
  "type": {
    "id": "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd"
  },
  "settings": {
     "minimumApproverCount": 1,
     "creatorVoteCounts": false,
     "allowDownvotes": false,
     "resetOnSourcePush": true,
     "scope": [
       {
         "refName": "refs/heads/features/",
         "matchKind": "prefix",
         "repositoryId": "ad3acf8e-b269-48e5-81bc-354251856b51"
       }

    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, was not aware of settings attributes.

Comment: The minimumApproverCount param, is it for required or optional reviewers ?